# How to make a Quarkus server starts when its DataSource is unable to connect to the DB or even if the database is down

Tags: hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I want to start my quarkus application and if the database is down, it cannot affect my startup.

My code: https://github.com/Uenderley/quarkus-datasources

**My pom.xml**

```
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus-plugin.version>1.11.3.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-universe-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>1.11.3.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**application.properties**

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.username=postgres
quarkus.datasource.password=postgres
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/users_db
quarkus.datasource.health.enabled=false
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=drop-and-create
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.min-size=0
```

**Error when I try to start my app when postgres is down**

```
WARN  [org.hib.eng.jdb.env.int.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] (Quarkus Main Thread) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5433 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:303)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:225)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:200)
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:452)
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:434)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at io.agroal.pool.util.PriorityScheduledExecutor.beforeExecute(PriorityScheduledExecutor.java:65)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1126)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Conexão recusada (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
        ... 12 more

2021-03-03 14:21:56,494 WARN  [io.agr.pool] (agroal-11) Datasource '<default>': Connection to localhost:5433 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
2021-03-03 14:21:56,495 WARN  [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (Quarkus Main Thread) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
2021-03-03 14:21:56,495 ERROR [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (Quarkus Main Thread) Connection to localhost:5433 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
2021-03-03 14:21:56,526 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application (with profile dev): java.net.ConnectException: Conexão recusada (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:225)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:200)
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:452)
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:434)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at io.agroal.pool.util.PriorityScheduledExecutor.beforeExecute(PriorityScheduledExecutor.java:65)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1126)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Quarkus application exited with code 1
Press Enter to restart or Ctrl + C to quit
2021-03-03 14:21:56,528 INFO  [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Attempting to start hot replacement endpoint to recover from previous Quarkus startup failure
```

**I know these properties on spring boot:**

spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never

Comment: It is not clear what do you want to achieve. Do you want your application to fail at startup if the database is not available? Do you want your application to re-establish the connection after the previous connection failure?

Comment: It looks like that he want the service to start up even if DB connection is not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to inject AgroalDataSource via method in order to fail if the DB is down only when you call the service.

Remove the *@Inject* and add this in your service method:

```
AgroalDataSource datasource = CDI.current().select(AgroalDataSource.class).get();
```

Import class:

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI;
```